# How to implement "finger-tracing" layer in app like the iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, uiview, touch-event

Now that our app has shipped, our person in charge of training has a request:

"The app is cool, but we need a mode showing the movement of the fingers, like how gestures show up in the Simulator or iPad's laser pointer mode in Keynote [so we can capture films]."

This is an app that uses a UITabBarController with xibs for each tab (4). This is a pretty complicated app with interacting gesture recognizers and I was having "first, do no harm" nightmares...

I tried adding a simple "global UIView" above the tab controller using the scheme here: http://www.james-vandyne.com/creating-universal-overlays-using-uiviews-on-ios/

My "PresentationView" attempt:

in my app delegate:

```
UIWindow *mainWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
[self setPresentationView:[[PresentationView alloc] initWithFrame: [mainWindow frame]]];
[mainWindow insertSubview:presentationView aboveSubview:mainWindow];
```

The class:

```
//  PresentationView.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PresentationView : UIView
{
    NSMutableDictionary *touchesInView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *touchesInView;
@end


#import "PresentationView.h"
#import "TouchPoint.h"

@implementation PresentationView
@synthesize touchesInView;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [ self setAlpha:0.1];
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [self setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
        touchesInView = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    [touchesInView release];
    touchesInView = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    if ([touchesInView count] < 1)
        return;

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    NSEnumerator *touchEnum = [touchesInView objectEnumerator];
    TouchPoint *nextTouch;
    float rad = 24;

    while (nextTouch = [touchEnum nextObject]) {
        [[ UIColor redColor] set];
        CGContextAddArc(context, nextTouch.current.x, nextTouch.current.y, rad, 0.0, M_PI*2, 1);
        CGContextFillPath(context);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
    }
}

- (UIView *) hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self setNeedsDisplay];

    return [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] subviews] objectAtIndex:0] hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for( UITouch *t in touches )
    {
        NSValue *key = [NSValue valueWithPointer:t];
        CGPoint loc = [t locationInView:self];
        TouchPoint *newTouch = [[TouchPoint alloc] init];

        [newTouch setBegan:loc];
        [newTouch setCurrent:loc];
        [newTouch setTapCount:[t tapCount]];

        [touchesInView setObject:newTouch forKey:key];

        [newTouch release];
    }
    [self setNeedsDisplay];

    [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] subviews] objectAtIndex:0] touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
// More touch methods- all ignored
```

This kinda works- the view sits atop all the other views, and `hitTest:withEvent:` fires, and I was successfully drawing a red circle at the hit point in `drawRect:`.

But it breaks down when I try to track touches- `touchesBegan/Moved/Ended` don't fire. (Yes, I have turned on `UserInteractionEnabled` and `setMultipleTouchEnabled` for this global view). Fortunately, I haven't screwed up gesture recognition on anything below- the other views are getting events, and the app is behaving normally under this global view.

Normally I use IB to build/locate views and don't build them in code from scratch, so it's very possible there's (a?/several?) simple UIView properties I'm not setting up right... but I can't see it. Or am I going to get myself in trouble with this, trying to forward events down the chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good framework called FingerTips that does this.

It's also easy to implement and it only shows the circles if there is an external display so you are presenting it.

Comment: For others future reference (a GIS for ios fingertips isn't terribly useful), the Fingertips framework is on GitHub. the branch I used: <https://github.com/correia/fingertips>. Was exactly what we needed, and light years ahead of anything I would have come up with. Thanks!